# A collinear problem involving three altitudes in a triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I found out this problem when I was fooling around with Geogebra. I've tried to solve it for some day but found nothing yet.

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle inscribed the circumcenter $(O)$, three
> altitudes $AD, BE, CF$. $AD$ intersects $(O)$ at $K$. Let $I$ be the
> midpoint of $EF$, $BI$ intersects $(O)$ at $J$. Prove that $K, E, J$
> are collinear.
> [image]

My attempts: Let $L$ be the intersection of $AO$ and $(O)$. It's a well-known result that $\widehat{LAC}=\widehat{KAB}$.

Since $\widehat{KJB}= \widehat{KAB}$ we need to prove that $\widehat{LAC}=\widehat{KJB}$ or if we let $Q$ be the intersection of $AL$ and $BJ$, we need to prove that $AJQE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

We see that $\widehat{AJB} = \widehat{ACB}$, so we deduce to prove that $QE \parallel BC$.

And I stuck here.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You already have the well-known result $\widehat{LAC}=\widehat{KAB}$ and $\widehat{KJB}=\widehat{KAB}$, then what is missing to prove $\widehat{LAC}=\widehat{KJB}$? Or did I misunderstood this goal?

Comment: @peterwhy $\widehat{LAC} = \widehat{KJB}$ but we haven't had $\widehat{LAC} = \widehat{EJB}$ yet.